# Android ImageLoader resize

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using ImageLoader (for the first time) to show image on my app. I show images with this :

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("http://www.web.com/pic_1.jpg", picture);
```

But picture is a imageview with width 200dp and height 100dp. How can i make the picture to fit in that resolution? whatever the picture is portrait or landscape.

Please help!

Comment: You can pass in a displayOptions to the image loader. See here for details: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Display-Options. You call it with displayImage(url, view, options) or whatever the overload is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FrameLayout` for your `ImageView` layout similar like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: noup. i can have 2 types of photo : portrait and landscape to fit in that 200dp/100dp

Comment: I use your code and add some custom code... and it solve my problem

Comment: Yes for `landscape` orientation, you should make seperate folder `drawable-land` to hold image for `landscape`